# Spring @Transaction wrapped around lambdas?

Tags: java, spring, lambda, transactions, spring-transactions

In a method like this, will the transaction be applied to all of the orderLineRespository.insertOrderLine() calls inside the lambda?

```
   @Transactional
    public OrderResponse createOrderTransactional(Order order) {
         checkForSomething(customerOrder);
         order.getOrderLines().forEach(line -> orderLineRepository.insertOrderLine(line);
         return new OrderResponse(order, true);
}
```

Comment: Yes. Just make sure you never make the stream processing go parallel. Which means that one of the main advantages of stream processing is void, so you might as well just use a normal `for` loop. In this particular case, though, stream is simpler, especially if you use method reference: `order.getOrderLines().forEach(orderLineRepository::insertOrderLine);`